# Wp-query 'post__not_in' doesn't work when I want to exclude some posts

Tags: wordpress

Here is my code and I'm trying to exclude some posts that have been added to the custom post type but it's not working for me, please if anyone can help me??

```
<div class="grid-x small-up-1 medium-up-3 large-up-3 gridi">
        <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
        <?php 
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'gallery',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post__not_in' => array (779, 1394, 774, 3278),
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="item-navigation">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="image-container">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            <div class="description">
                                <h5 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: How is this not working? What did you expect and what happened instead?

Comment: at archive page I want to exclude those pages with post ID (779, 1394, 774, 3278) but "post__not_in" doesnt work

Comment: "Doesn't work" is unspecific. Please explain exactly how it is not working. Do you have error messages? What do you experience exactly and what are you expecting? You cannot expect a detailed answer if you do not provide details yourself in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line..:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

... simply executes the global wp_query. The query you declare the line above as $loop isn't used.

Try:

```
<?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```